# Getting an error of incompatible types and I cannot find the issue

Tags: java, methods, static

I'm a beginner and I've just gotten to static methods so they're a bit confusing for me still because of the strange flow of control. What is causing the error here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class GravityV1
{
public static double gravityCalculation(double[] planetMass, int[] planetDiameter)
{
    double universalGravityConst = 6.67E-11;
    double [] surfaceGravity = new double [planetMass.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < planetMass.length; i++)
        surfaceGravity[i] = ((universalGravityConst * planetMass[i]) / (Math.pow(planetDiameter[i] / 2, 2)));
    return surfaceGravity;
}


public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String [] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
    double [] mass = {3.3022E23, 4.8685E24, 5.97E24, 6.4185E23, 1.8986E27, 5.6846E26, 8.6810E25, 10.243E25};
    int [] diameter = {4879, 12104, 12576, 6792, 142984, 120536, 51118, 49528};

    double [] gravities = gravityCalculation(mass, diameter);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

```
double [] gravities = gravityCalculation(mass, diameter);
```

your  gravityCalculation(mass, diameter); returns a double primitive and you are assigning it to a double[] array thus the error.

change your

```
public static double gravityCalculation(double[] planetMass, int[] planetDiameter) 
     to
public static double[] gravityCalculation(double[] planetMass, int[] planetDiameter)
```